# How UTM paramters reach to Google Analystics Website

Tags: google-analytics, utm-tracking

I am bit confused, and need little help regarding UTM tracking parameters.

Standard syntax of UTM url is:

http://www.example.com/?utm_source=adsite&utm_campaign=adcampaign.

Lets say I embed this url as a link in my page. User clicks this link. Link is pointing to my website.

All utm parameters would reach to my website. How do they will reach to Google analytics website.

My guess is, Analytics code and js intercept all link clicks and extract UTM params and then let user defined click handler work with the click.

Could someone with right expertise would help me?.

Thank you very much for your time, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UTM require following mandatory parameters:

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=adsite&utm_medium=admedium
```

**utm_source** and **utm_medium** are mandatory.

***utm_campaign*** is not mandatory even if the documentation says otherwise.

Google Analytics automatically collects these parameters and automatically removes them from the URL so in Google Analytics you will see the URLs without parameters and the source / medium of the UTM.

Comment: I am sorry, but my question is this: given url is destined for www.example.com server, how come google analytics server gets the utm parameters.

Comment: It happens because on the destination page (www.example.com) the Google tracking code (analytics.js o gtag.gs) acquires the URL and automatically checks and processes if there are UTM parameters. Obviously the tracking code must be present on the landing page.

Comment: thank you so much for clarification, I assume, tracking code adds click handlers to all the links on the page to intercept clicks. .

Comment: Analytics detects UTM not onclick but when URL is opened (onload or when analytics js code is ready when page is opened).